# Having trouble installing pylibmc OSX 10.9

Tags: python, libmemcached

I've installed libmemcached with homebrew, and tried to install pylibmc with PIP but to no avail:

```
Downloading/unpacking pylibmc==1.2.2
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pylibmc

Installing collected packages: pylibmc
  Running setup.py install for pylibmc
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -DUSE_ZLIB -I/usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.17/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
    _pylibmcmodule.c:497:9: warning: variable 'res0' is used uninitialized whenever 'if' condition is false [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _pylibmcmodule.c:528:9: note: uninitialized use occurs here
        if (res0 != NULL) {
            ^~~~
    _pylibmcmodule.c:497:5: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
        if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _pylibmcmodule.c:474:36: note: initialize the variable 'res0' to silence this warning
        memcached_result_st *res, *res0;
                                       ^
                                        = NULL
    _pylibmcmodule.c:1890:9: error: unknown type name 'memcached_server_instance_st'; did you mean 'memcached_server_list_st'?
            memcached_server_instance_st svr = NULL;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            memcached_server_list_st
    /usr/local/Cellar/libmemcached/1.0.17/include/libmemcached-1.0/types.h:75:37: note: 'memcached_server_list_st' declared here
    typedef struct memcached_server_st *memcached_server_list_st;
                                        ^
    _pylibmcmodule.c:1892:13: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'memcached_server_list_st' (aka 'struct memcached_server_st *') from 'const memcached_instance_st *' (aka 'const struct memcached_instance_st *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            svr = memcached_server_by_key(mc, key, len, &rc);
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    2 warnings and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I found this link - http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/install.html#requirements but am not sure what to put as the LIBMEMCACHED path - as I've installed that via homebrew - I have tried a few paths, but all paths give the same error as above.